# How to avoid/skip the text finding inside the Hidden/Non-displayed content in CKEDITOR 4.0

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using an CKEDITOR 4.0. And i have an content HTML as below

```
<p>First content para on Ckeditor</p>
<p style="display:none">Second content Para with display none in ckeditor contains text ramesh</p>
<p>third content para on ckeditor</p>
```

Now the ckeditor shows only first and third `<p>` tag contents only.

When i try to find the the text 'ramesh' using the find plugin in the toolbar, its not throwing alert box as 'The specified text not found'. its finding the text inside the hiddedn para also. How can i avoid this.

Is it possible to do this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment CKEditor doesn't offer such feature. You need to modify the source code of the [find plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/find) to have this working your way.

Created a new ticket for this bug on [CKEditor bug tracker](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10641). Hopefully we'll see this fixed soon ;)